# Pig write to S3 via HCatStorer() "succeeds" with 0-bytes written

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-pig, emr, hcatalog

I created an external Hive (1.0 on EMR) table that is stored in S3. I can successfully use Hive to insert records into this table, query them back, and pull the files directly from the S3 bucket as verification. So far, so good.

I would like to be able to use Pig (v0.14, also on EMR) to both read and write to this logical table. Loading with HCatLoader() works fine, and dump/explain confirm that my data and schema are as expected.

When I try to write with HCatStorer() however, I have problems. Pig reports success, with N records, **but 0 bytes**, written. I see nothing that seems relevant or indicative of a problem in the log, and no data is  written into the table/bucket.

```
a = load 'myfile' as (foo: int, bar: chararray); // Just assume that this works. 
dump a; // Records are there
describe a; // Correct schema, as specified above
store a into 'mytable' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

The output (which, again contains no other indication of problems that I can see) concludes with:

```
Success!

...

Input(s):
Successfully read 2 records (24235 bytes) from: "myfile"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 2 records in: "mytable"

Counters:
Total records written : 2
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0
```

Of note:

- This works in the same environment if the table location is in HDFS instead of S3 - for both external and internal tables, and from either Hive or Pig.
- I can successfully store directly to S3 with e.g. `store a into 's3n://mybucket/output' using PigStorage(',');`
- An insert via the Hive shell to the same query works fine.

So this appears to be a problem with the interplay of Pig/HCatalog/S3 as a stack; any two of these together seem to work fine.

Given that I don't see anything very useful in the Pig log, what else should I look at to debug this? Are there any particular configuration parameters for any of these technologies that I should look at?

Comment: hey...!
you have mentioned that you are unable to store the data in hive table even though it says that data is "successfully stored", can you check in HDFS and locate the path of "mytable" and see if any data is present?

Comment: @Pratik In the error case, "mytable" lives in S3, not HDFS... that's the crux of the challenge here! When I do a version of this where "mytable" is located in HDFS, it works fine, and data appears there as expected.

Comment: @Greg did you ever find a solution other than staging in emr? I need to use pig to load hive table on s3. thinking about using a workaround of just landing the data in the folder and using a lambda function to add the partition in hive, but would prefer an all pig solution

Comment: @TaylerJones no, at least not if you need dynamic partitioning. I do recall that you could get it to work using the s3a protocol if the table was also statically partitioned.

Comment: @Greg thanks man - only doing static partitions and using s3a worked perfectly. You're a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a issue when you write to S3 from pig using HCatalog.
Since the final output data is being written to an _temporary file and is never being copied/ moved to the original location. This weird behavior is encountered only on S3.

In my case the output should be written to s3://x/y/ , but the data was written to
s3://x/y/**_temporary/attempt_1466700620679_0019_r_000000_0/part-r-00000**

Workaround for this was writing the output from HCatalog to HDFS and then to S3.

You can refer to the below link posted on aws forum:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230544

Comment: Yes thanks... that AWS forum post and workaround was mine! :-) Still +1 for the link - helps track the different thread for this answer here.